# How to split child node into multiple sibling child nodes each with a single subnode

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am a newbie at XSLT, so I'm asking for assistance.  I have a number of XML documents of which the following is a representative example.  The documents are divided into `<sub-doc(n)>` elements, which are further divided into `<section>` elements.  Within the sections are ZERO or more `<heading>` elements, and ONE or more `<paragraph>` elements.  My goal is to ensure that every section has at most ONE `<heading>` element by dividing those sections that do have more than one heading into multiple sections with one heading in each.  When this is done, the `<paragraph>` elements immediately following a `<heading>` have to go with the `<heading>` into the new `<section>`.  For example, note that in the following example the first `<section>` of `<sub-doc1>` has two `<heading>` elements.  I need to break this `<section>` element into TWO `<section>` elements, each with its own `<heading>` and follow-up `<paragraph>` elements.

```
<document>
 <sub-doc1>
  <section> <!-- This section needs to be split -->
   <heading>Subdoc1 first heading text</heading>
   <paragraph>A lot of text</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Yet more text</paragraph>
   <paragraph>More text</paragraph>
   ...
   <heading>Subdoc1 second heading text</heading>
   <paragraph>Even more text</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Some text</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
  <section>
   <paragraph>Even more text</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
 </sub-doc1>
 <sub-doc2>
  <section>
   <heading>Subdoc2, first heading text</heading>
   <paragraph>A lot of text here</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Yet more text here</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Yet more text here</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
 </sub-doc2>
</document>
```

That is, the transformed document needs to look like this:

```
<document>
 <sub-doc1>
  <section> <!-- This section got split into two sections -->
   <heading>Subdoc1 first heading text</heading>
   <paragraph>A lot of text</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Yet more text</paragraph>
   <paragraph>More text</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
  <section> <!-- This is a new section -->
   <heading>Subdoc1 second heading text</heading>
   <paragraph>Even more text</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Some text</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
  <section>
   <paragraph>Even more text</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
 </sub-doc1>
 <sub-doc2>
  <section>
   <heading>Subdoc2, first heading text</heading>
   <paragraph>A lot of text here</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Yet more text here</paragraph>
   <paragraph>Yet more text here</paragraph>
   ...
  </section>
 </sub-doc2>
</document>
```

Note that some sections do not have `<heading>` elements at all.  In those cases, those sections should remain the same.  Also, some sections have only a single `<heading>`.  Those sections should also remain the same.  And everything else in the document should remain the same.  The only transformation that needs to occur is in those cases where a `<section>` anywhere in the document has more than one `<heading>`.

Again, I am new to XSLT, and can't get my head around the XSL that would accomplish the task.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet does as you ask. It uses a key to select all `paragraph` elements corresponding to a given heading.

The output I show corresponds to your sample input with the ellipses removed.

Note that this solution requires that all
`section` elements that contain any `heading` elements have a `heading` element as the first child. i.e. there are no `paragraph` elements before the first `heading`.
If this assumption is wrong then the stylesheet will need a small change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="paragraph-for-heading" match="paragraph" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::heading[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section[heading]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="heading"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="heading">
    <section>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('paragraph-for-heading', generate-id())"/>
    </section>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<document>
   <sub-doc1>
      <section>
         <heading>Subdoc1 first heading text</heading>
         <paragraph>A lot of text</paragraph>
         <paragraph>Yet more text</paragraph>
         <paragraph>More text</paragraph>
      </section>
      <section>
         <heading>Subdoc1 second heading text</heading>
         <paragraph>Even more text</paragraph>
         <paragraph>Some text</paragraph>
      </section>
      <section>
         <paragraph>Even more text</paragraph>
      </section>
   </sub-doc1>
   <sub-doc2>
      <section>
         <heading>Subdoc2, first heading text</heading>
         <paragraph>A lot of text here</paragraph>
         <paragraph>Yet more text here</paragraph>
         <paragraph>Yet more text here</paragraph>
      </section>
   </sub-doc2>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks, Borodin...!  That works perfectly!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

I am able to generate the output that you are looking for.  This type of processing for me has required using preceeding-sibling in XPath to grab the group elements that I am looking for, when they exist between another set of elements.

Since you also had some sections without headers, I had to process those sections differently.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="document">
    <document>
      <!-- Select the sub-doc elements and print their names, then process their children -->
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
          <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <!-- For a section with 1 or more headings -->
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="count(heading) &gt; 0">
                <!-- Print each section, heading and the paragraphs that follow -->
                <xsl:for-each select="heading">
                  <xsl:variable name="currentHeading" select="current()"/>
                  <section>
                    <heading>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </heading>
                    <!-- Pick paragraphs that follow current heading -->
                    <xsl:variable name="paragraphList" select="../paragraph[preceding-sibling::heading[1] = $currentHeading]"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$paragraphList">
                      <paragraph>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                      </paragraph>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </section>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <section>
                  <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
                    <paragraph>
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </paragraph>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </section>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Niraj